# stop automatical convert to htmlentities?

Tags: javascript

I have a div id="ultimativegodemperorofalldivs"
It contains some Text like "such a cool & sexy div"

when I extract the InnerHTML with JS it converts the `&` to `&amp;`
I really don't want this. I don't need it for URL's so it really should be a very simple `&`.
How to archive this?

Thx in Advance,
iceteea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like its name says, `innerHTML` retrieves the element’s inner HTML.  Without HTML entities, it wouldn’t be valid HTML.  If you want to retrieve the element’s text content, you’ll have to use the element’s `textContent` or `innerText` properties.

(`innerText` is only supported in IE; but `textContent` is not supported by older versions of IE).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using innerHTML.you can use innerText

```
document.getElementById('ultimativegodemperorofalldivs').innerText
```

Hope this helps!!!!